# Balkan MO 2018 Problem 1 about a complete cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math, quadrilateral

> (BMO 2018 Q1) A quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle $k$, where $AB > CD$ and $AB$ is not
> parallel to $CD$. Point $M$ is the intersection of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ and the
> perpendicular from $M$ to $AB$ intersects the segment $AB$ at the point $E$. If $EM$ bisects
> the angle $CED$, prove that $AB$ is a diameter of the circle $k$.

My solutions are different from the official solution in https://bmo2018.dms.rs/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Solutions.pdf, I am not sure these solutions are correct. Any constructive comments on my solution will be much appreciated.

[image]

Solution-1: Let $O$ be the center of circle $k$, Let $AB ∩ DC = P$ and $AD ∩ BC = Q$. We have a completed cyclic quadrilateral ($ABCDPQ$). Let $OM ∩ PQ = N$. By the properties of completed cyclic quadrilateral, we have $O,M,N$ are collinear.
By Brocard Theorem, $△PMQ$ is self-polar and $O$ is the orthocenter of $△PMQ$, this implied that $QM ⊥ PO = E'$ and $OM ⊥ PQ = N$, we are given $ME ⊥ AB$, and we have $OP ≡ AB$, $⇒ E'= E$, $⇒ O$ must on $AB$, and $AB$ is the diameter.

Solution-2: Let $AB ∩ DC = P$ and $AD ∩ BC = Q$. We have a completed cyclic quadrilateral ($ABCDPQ$). Apply “Cevians induces harmonic lemma” on $△QAB$ we have -1 = ($P,E;A,E$), by the converse of “inversion induces harmonic lemma”, we can conclude that AB is the diameter of the circle $k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I have included the picture into your text.

Comment: There is an error in $AB \cap CD=\color{red}{P}$

Comment: 2 question : 1) why can you say that OM ⊥ PQ ? 2) Where do you use the fact that line EM bisects angle CED ?

Comment: Hello Jean Marie, thanks for pointing out the typo. 1) please refer to Property 19.10 of the book "A Beautiful JourneyThrough Olympiad Geometry" by Stefan Lozanovski . 2) I do not need to use this fact in my solution.

Comment: (I tried to up the contrast of the image)

Comment: Thanks, Calvin!